# Sending a char array to a thread using CreateThread in C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

I have a server program that accepts multiple clients. Now the problem is how to send the data that I received from the client inside a thread,that needed to sent to other client.

That is : the data or the message I received from the client at the server should be sent to the other client simultaneously. For this task I started a thread whenever I get the data from the client and sending the string to the thread. But in the thread when I just display the message it is not showing anything. How to fix this please.

**My Server Program:**

```
//This server receives data from single client
//This is a  server

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <thread>
#include "sendingclient.h"
#include "server.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

BOOL bOptVal = FALSE;
WSADATA WsaDat;
SOCKET Socket;  
DWORD WINAPI ProcessClient (LPVOID lpParameter);
DWORD WINAPI sendToTaxServer (LPVOID lpParameter);

void Server :: start_server_listening() //listen to multiple clients
{

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat)!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"WSA Initialization failed!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);       

    if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout<<"Socket creation failed.\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");

    }

    SOCKADDR_IN serverInf;
    serverInf.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverInf.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serverInf.sin_port=htons(8888);

    if (setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &bOptVal, sizeof(bOptVal)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(bind(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&serverInf),sizeof(serverInf))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout<<"Unable to bind socket!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
    }

    else
    {   
      listen(Socket,3);
      SOCKET  AcceptSocket;

  while (1)
    {
        AcceptSocket = SOCKET_ERROR;

        while (AcceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            AcceptSocket = accept( Socket, NULL, NULL );
        }

        printf( "Client Connected.\n");

        DWORD dwThreadId; //starting thread to accept data from the client
        CreateThread (NULL, 0, ProcessClient, (LPVOID) AcceptSocket, 0, &dwThreadId);
    }

  }
}

DWORD WINAPI ProcessClient (LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    SOCKET AcceptSocket = (SOCKET) lpParameter;

    // Send and receive data.

    while(1)
   {
       char buffer[1000];
        memset(buffer,0,999);
        int inDataLength=recv(AcceptSocket,buffer,1000,0);
        //std::cout<<buffer;
        DWORD dwThreadId1; //send the received data to other thread
        CreateThread (NULL, 0, sendToTaxServer, &message, 0, &dwThreadId1); 
      if (inDataLength == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {
        printf("Client Disconnected\n");
        Sleep(2000);
            break;
      }
   }
    closesocket(AcceptSocket);
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI sendToTaxServer (LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    char *message = (char*)lpParameter;
    std::cout<<message<<std::endl;  //**Message Not showing up.A blank line**
    Sleep(5000);
    //send to other client

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `CopyMemory(message, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`? You read to `buffer`, but pass some `message` instead, what is the message, where it fill?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is just a string.I get the string from Client

Comment: Just spawn on thread and then use a queue to communicated between the threads by setting an event that the transmitting thread is waiting on. Make sure that you guard the queue by a semaphore for thread safety.